# Getting "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'" error while replacing string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column which has text in it. I have to replace (':',' ').

When I am running this code:

```
df["text"] = [x.replace(':',' ') for x in df["text"]]
```

I am facing the this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-13-3c116e6f21e2> in <module>
  1 #df["text"] = df["text"].astype(str)
----> 2 df["text"] = [x.replace(':',' ') for x in df["text"]]

<ipython-input-13-3c116e6f21e2> in <listcomp>(.0)
  1 #df["text"] = data["NOTES_ENT"].astype(str)
----> 2 df["text"] = [x.replace(':',' ') for x in df["text"]]

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me?

Comment: It seems that you have a float type in the field of "test" in the data frame

Answer (score 7):

The error is pretty clear. you are trying to replace characters in a float. x probably is a float. you might want to do str(x) which gets you

```py
f["text"] = [str(x).replace(':',' ') for x in df["text"]]
```

but i can't see a situation where a float contains a :

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion problem is missing value in column, so use pandas methods [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead list comprehension:

```
df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(':',' ')
```

Or:

```
df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(':',' ', regex=True)
```

Solution with list comprehension is possible, only need if-else statement for test strings:

```
df["text"] = [x.replace(':',' ') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in df["text"]]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['qq:ww','e:', np.nan]})
df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(':',' ')

print (df)
    text
0  qq ww
1     e 
2    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try writing adding above line to your code and let me know if that works for you.

```
df["text"] = df["text"].astype(str)
df["text"] = [x.replace(':',' ') for x in df["text"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As the indicated in the error message, **text** must be string. You may try changing data type:

```
text = str(text)
```